# Scheduled Task in XP: Disable "Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins" in command line

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to disable the `Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins` option on some scheduled tasks on our client machines by using the command line. It appears that in Vista and above there is a `/K` option that allows this, but no such switch exists in XP.
Is there no way to change this using command line? If not, could you recommend a C# library that would let me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more looking I didn't find anything, so I'm instead using the CodeProject [Task Scheduler](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx) library.